# Vuetify not displaying properly after deployment

Tags: css, azure, vue.js, deployment, vuetify.js

I built a spa that uses vue.js for the frontend. Specifically, I use the vuetify library for many components and layout. The site looks beautiful when running locally. I just deployed it to Azure, and all vuetify styling seems gone. Any custom css that I wrote is taking effect, but anything that belongs to vuetify simply doesn't appear with their styling. There are no error messages in the developer console. Any insight?

Comment: Can you describe the steps you too to deploy it? Sounds like the CSS is not getting loaded and may not have been uploaded

Comment: It is due to your web server configuration it seems..please check the console. whether all the css js files loaded n browser. If you get any 404 errors, please make changes to your web server configuration

Comment: I simply published to azure manually via visual studio. There are no 404 errors in the console. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `plugins/vuetify.js` file, make sure you include the minified vuetify CSS as below (see [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start)):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' // <<< THIS

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
});
```

I was missing that line and had the same symptom - styling looked fine locally (lots of `style` tags included in `head` element) but not in Azure static web app.